# Generalized linear model Gaussian distribution Linear Model

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, terminology

Is a generalized linear model with a Gaussian distribution the same as a linear model?

Comment: If using an identity link, yes, I think it is but not confident enough to post as an answer!

Comment: @tristan: Not necessarily, think e.g. about a linear model that optimizes L1 loss instead of squared loss. The Gaussian GLM with identity link is essentially identical to the corresponding least squares model.

Comment: @MichaelM good point, that's why I didn't add as an answer because I wasn't confident of caveats etc

Answer (score 1):

Essentially yes, if you think about a gaussian generalized linear model (glm) with identity link function, then that is the same as what is usually meant with a linear model.

But, "linear model" could be used with other shades of meaning, like estimating it with some other loss function than sum of squares. And a gaussian glm could use some other link function than the identity.

Comment: What about having unknown variance $\sigma^2$ in the "linear model"?

Answer (score 0):

In the generalized linear model (specially meant for classification problem), the source of non-linearity is activation funtion with linear argument of the form $\omega^\top x +\omega_0$. Here, we just need to estimate the parameters $\omega, \omega_0$ only and the activation might be user defined.

While, in regression problem, the using least square estimation, the prediction function happens to be a conditional expectation of the form $E(y|x)$. If the joint distribution of x and y is Gaussian, then the prediction function $E(y|x)=\omega_0 + \omega^\top x$ linear both in the parameters $\omega, \ \omega_0$ and in the predictor x.